# Using adversarial loss in GANEstimator

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning, keras

I'm now trying to combine an L1 pixel loss and an adversarial loss to learn to autoencode images. The code would be as follows.

```
gan_model = tfgan.gan_model(
    generator_fn=nets.autoencoder,
    discriminator_fn=nets.discriminator,
    real_data=images,
    generator_inputs=images)

gan_loss = tfgan.gan_loss(
    gan_model,
    generator_loss_fn=tfgan.losses.wasserstein_generator_loss,
    discriminator_loss_fn=tfgan.losses.wasserstein_discriminator_loss,
    gradient_penalty=1.0)
l1_pixel_loss = tf.norm(gan_model.real_data - gan_model.generated_data, ord=1)

# Modify the loss tuple to include the pixel loss.
gan_loss = tfgan.losses.combine_adversarial_loss(
    gan_loss, gan_model, l1_pixel_loss,
    weight_factor=FLAGS.weight_factor)

# Create the train ops, which calculate gradients and apply updates to weights.
train_ops = tfgan.gan_train_ops(
    gan_model,
    gan_loss,
    generator_optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(gen_lr, 0.5),
    discriminator_optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(dis_lr, 0.5))

# Run the train ops in the alternating training scheme.
tfgan.gan_train(
    train_ops,
    hooks=[tf.train.StopAtStepHook(num_steps=FLAGS.max_number_of_steps)],
    logdir=FLAGS.train_log_dir)
```

However, I'd like to use GANEstimator to simplify the code. The typical example of GANEstimator is as follows.

```
gan_estimator = tfgan.estimator.GANEstimator(
    model_dir,
    generator_fn=generator_fn,
    discriminator_fn=discriminator_fn,
    generator_loss_fn=tfgan.losses.wasserstein_generator_loss,
    discriminator_loss_fn=tfgan.losses.wasserstein_discriminator_loss,
    generator_optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.1, 0.5),
    discriminator_optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.1, 0.5))

# Train estimator.
gan_estimator.train(train_input_fn, steps)
```

Does anyone know how to use **combine_adversarial_loss** in GANEstimator?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered the same problem (this solution is working on TensorFlow r1.12).

Reading through the code, [`tfgan.losses.combine_adversarial_loss`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.12/tensorflow/contrib/gan/python/losses/python/tuple_losses_impl.py) takes `gan_loss` tuple and replace generator loss with combine adversarial loss. That means that we need to replace `generator_loss_fn` in the estimator. All other loss functions for estimator takes arguments: `gan_model, **kwargs`. We define our own function and use it as generator loss function:

```
def combined_loss(gan_model, **kwargs):
    # Define non-adversarial loss - for example L1
    non_adversarial_loss = tf.losses.absolute_difference(
        gan_model.real_data, gan_model.generated_data)
    # Define generator loss
    generator_loss = tf.contrib.gan.losses.wasserstein_generator_loss(
        gan_model,
        **kwargs)
    # Combine these losses - you can specify more parameters
    # Exactly one of weight_factor and gradient_ratio must be non-None
    combined_loss = tf.contrib.gan.losses.wargs.combine_adversarial_loss(
        non_adversarial_loss,
        generator_loss,
        weight_factor=FLAGS.weight_factor,
        gradient_ratio=None,
        variables=gan_model.generator_variables,
        scalar_summaries=kwargs['add_summaries'],
        gradient_summaries=kwargs['add_summaries'])
    return combined_loss


gan_estimator = tf.contrib.gan.estimator.GANEstimator(
    model_dir,
    generator_fn=generator_fn,
    discriminator_fn=discriminator_fn,
    generator_loss_fn=combined_loss,
    discriminator_loss_fn=tfgan.losses.wasserstein_discriminator_loss,
    generator_optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4, 0.5),
    discriminator_optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4, 0.5))
```

For more information about parameters, docs: [`tfgan.losses.wargs.combine_adversarial_loss`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/gan/losses/wargs/combine_adversarial_loss)
Also the `**kwargs` aren't compatible with the combined adversarial loss function, so I use there a small hack.

Answer (score 0):

From your link, GANEstimator has the following parameters:

```
 generator_loss_fn=None,
 discriminator_loss_fn=None,
```

`generator_loss_fn` should be your l1 pixel loss.

`discriminator_loss_fn` should be your combine_adversarial_loss.

Comment: So the pixel loss can either go into the generator loss or the discriminator loss?